# c++ files and variables

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file and use the first integer on a line as a variable
`s`.
My function can read the file and write to another but it will not store the first number as the variable

```
void process_file(ifstream& in, ofstream& out)
{
 string i,o;
char tmp;
int s;
prompt_user(i,o);
in.open (i.c_str());
if (in.fail())
{
    cout << "Error opening " << i << endl;
    exit(1);
}
    out.open(o.c_str());

while(tmp !='\n')
{
    in.get(tmp);
    s=tmp;
}
cout << tmp;
in.get(tmp);

while (tmp !='\n')
{
    out.put(tmp);
    in.get(tmp);
}
in.close();
out.close();


}
```

here is what i get when reading a file that looks like this..

4
lastName1 firstName1
lastname2 firstName2
lastName3 firstName3
.....

Enter the name of the file containing salespersons' names and daily sales for some number of weeks.
somedat.dat
Enter the name of the file in which to store a summary of the total sales and average sales.
od.dat

10
(the last and first name of the first is properly outputted into the other file as expected 10 should be 4 though..)

Comment: What is `s`? Can you describe your problem/sample output more clearly?

Comment: s is just a variable I used for the integer (number of students) the file it is to read looks like

Comment: Can you show an example of running the program?

Comment: `tmp` is a `char`. The statement `s=tmp` assigns the value of the `char` that is read from `in`, not the number itself. Since it is in a while loop, if your first line is e.g. `1234`, then `s` is assigned the ASCII value of `4`. However, I think you want `s` to be assigned `1234`, is that correct?

Comment: I made it more clear.S should be 4 as it is the first integer on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is to get the first line in your input file, which is a number, and store it in `s`. You can use `stringstream` and `getline` to do this:

```
void process_file(ifstream& in, ofstream& out)
{
 string i,o;
char tmp;
int s;
prompt_user(i,o);
in.open (i.c_str());
if (in.fail())
{
    cout << "Error opening " << i << endl;
    exit(1);
}
    out.open(o.c_str());


//assuming the number is on a separate line by itself
string line;
getline(in, line);
stringstream linestream(line);
linestream >> s;

//while you can read from the input, write what you read directly to the output
while(getline(in, line))
  out << line;

in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: you dont know a way too keep this as one function do you. I understand you can just use a function to read the first line. But i need to be able to read the rest as well. I makes since to just do it as a single function therefore. what it should do is store the first integer as a variable so I can process the rest.

Comment: If you mean you want to read each of the other lines the same way, you can just put the whole `getline` thing in a while loop, instead of reading character by character as you are doing. I'll edit it in a second to reflect this ...

Comment: Done! Actually, didn't need getline after the first time.

Comment: Never mind, actually I think I did because without the getline the spaces would get ignored.

Comment: I haven't tested this so you should try it out first. My point was to demonstrate that you can read/write/process more than just single characters at a time.